# python, basic lambda function

Tags: python

I am a c++ guy, learning the lambda function in python and wanna know it inside out. did some seraches before posting here. anyway, this piece of code came up to me.

<1> i dont quite understand the purpose of lambda function here. r we trying to get a function template? If so, why dont we just set up 2 parameters in the function input?

<2> also, `make_incrementor(42)`, at this moment is equivalent to return `x+42`, and x is the `0`,`1` in `f(0)` and `f(1)`?

<3> for `f(0)`, does it not have the same effect as `>>>f = make_incrementor(42)`? for `f(0)`, what are the values for `x` and `n` respectively?

any commments are welcome! thanks.

```
>>> def make_incrementor(n):
... return lambda x: x + n
...
>>> f = make_incrementor(42)
>>> f(0)
42
>>> f(1)
43
```

Comment: this is a very basic example. `make_incrementor` returns a lambda, which is a function. It can be used in cases where you need a function, such as in the `map` function. Consider this: `map(f, range(0,10))` will return you a list of numbers from `42` to `51`. You need a function for map that takes only 1 parameter.

Comment: just added a follow up question 3 just now @njzk2

Comment: Just for reference here's a [lambda tutorial](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/) that I've found particularly useful

Comment: Keep in mind, a `lambda` expression simply creates a new function object. `f = lamba x: x + n` and `def f(x): return x + n` produce identical function objects bound to `f`.

Comment: `f` is a function such as `f(x) = x+n`, n being the parameter give to `make_incrementor`, i.e. 42, x being the parameter to f. so `f = make_incrementor(42)` gives you `f(x) = x + 42`, and then `f(0) = 0 + 42`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, this is similar to a C++ `int` template. However, instead of at compile time (yes, Python (at least for CPython) is "compiled"), the function is created at run time. Why the lambda is used in this specific case is unclear, probably only for demonstration that functions can be returned from other functions rather than practical use. Sometimes, however, statements like this may be necessary if you need a function taking a specified number of arguments (e.g. for `map`, the function must take the same number of arguments as the number of iterables given to `map`) but the behaviour of the function should depend on other arguments.
2. `make_incrementor` returns a function that adds `n` (here, `42`) to any `x` passed to that function. In your case the `x` values you tried are `0` and `1``
3. `f = make_incrementor(42)` sets `f` to a *function* that returns `x + 42`. `f(0)`, however, returns `0 + 42`, which is `42` - the returned types and values are both different, so the different expressions don't have the same effect.

Comment: Note that `map` is perfectly happy taking multiple arguments, eg: `map(operator.add, [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])` is `[5, 7, 9]` - the `lambda` in the example is used to purely *fix* one of those arguments in place... it's also sometimes possible to use `functools.partial` for this depending on argument ordering etc... eg: `map(functools.partial(operator.add, 42), range(10))`

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to show a toy lambda return. It lets you create a function with data baked in. I have used this less trivial example of a similar use.

```
def startsWithFunc(testString):
    return lambda x: x.find(testString) == 0
```

Then when I am parsing, I create some functions:

```
startsDesctription   = startsWithFunc("!Sample_description")
startMatrix          = startsWithFunc("!series_matrix_table_begin")
```

Then in code I use:

```
 while line:
    #.... other stuff

    if startsDesctription(line):
        #do description work

    if startMatrix(line):
        #do matrix start work

    #other stuff ... increment line ... etc
```

Still perhaps trival, but it shows creating general funcitons with data baked it.